# combobox not updating? VB.net

Tags: vb.net, combobox, refresh

I'm unable to update the contents in combobox2 when I change my selection in combobox1, what am I missing or doing wrong?

```
  Imports System.IO
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'get sub directory\ toolpalette group names...
        ComboBox1.DataSource = New DirectoryInfo("C:\VTS\TREADSTONE LT\ATC").GetDirectories()

        Dim filelocation As String
        filelocation = ("C:\VTS\TREADSTONE LT\ATC\" & ComboBox1.Text & "\")

        'gets file\ paltte names...
        For Each BackupFiles As String In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(filelocation, FileIO.SearchOption.SearchTopLevelOnly, "*.*")
            ComboBox2.Items.Add(IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(BackupFiles))
        Next

        'reloads the combobox contents...
        ComboBox1.Refresh()

    End Sub


End Class
```

Comment: "what am I missing " - a combobox1 selection changed event handler?

Comment: I would recommend reading: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973905.aspx

Comment: @MitchWheat I'm thinking the only thing i want to do is cut and paste everything from  "Dim filelocation As String" downward under the combobox1 selection change event still nothing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ComboBox1 SelectedIndexChanged event handler should be like this ..

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged

  if ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1 then exit sub

  Dim filelocation As String
  filelocation = ("C:\VTS\TREADSTONE LT\ATC\" & ComboBox1.Text & "\")

  ComboBox2.Items.Clear() '---> clearing combobox2 list

  'gets file\ paltte names...
  For Each BackupFiles As String In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(filelocation, FileIO.SearchOption.SearchTopLevelOnly, "*.*")
        ComboBox2.Items.Add(IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(BackupFiles))
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Well that works, though ill pull it apart to understand it better many thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

When the combobox1 selected item changes you need to intercept the event adding an appropriate event handler, then, in this event, refill the second combo with the file names.

However you fill the first combo with a list of DirectoryInfo objects, when you retrieve this objects you have DirectoryInfo not a string. You should extract the DirectoryInfo object and use the FullName property to find the files required

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, _
    ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged


    ' First clear the Items collection of the second combo
    ComboBox2.Items.Clear()

    ' Now checks if you have really something selected
    Dim comboBox As comboBox = CType(sender, comboBox)
    if comboBox.SelectedItem Is Nothing Then
        Return
    End If


    Dim di = CType(comboBox.SelectedItem, DirectoryInfo)
    Dim filelocation = di.FullName

    For Each BackupFiles As String In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(filelocation, FileIO.SearchOption.SearchTopLevelOnly, "*.*")
        ComboBox2.Items.Add(IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(BackupFiles))
    Next

End Sub
```